# Parent CollectionView returning nil after selecting Child Cell

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uicollectionview, datasource

Im attempting to set up a colletionView inside a collectionView with separation between the data sources so its easier for me to manipulate UI elements.

I have my main ViewController which sets the datasource and delegate of the "outer" collection view.

```
class DownloadCollectionController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var outerCollectionView: UICollectionView!
var outerDataProvider : OuterDatasourceDelegate!
var outerDelegate: OuterDatasourceDelegate!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // set the datasource fot the outer collection
    outerDataProvider = OuterDatasourceDelegate()

    // crashes on this line when selecting a cell
    outerCollectionView.dataSource = outerDataProvider

    outerDelegate = OuterDatasourceDelegate()
    outerCollectionView.delegate = outerDelegate
}
}
```

The OuterDatasourceDelegate class which has some functions to populate the cell and then the willDisplayAt function the sets the datasource and delegate for the 'inner" collection view:

```
class OuterDatasourceDelegate: NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {


func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return GlobalOperationStore.sharedInstance.globalPackArray.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    // cell stuff...
    return outerCell
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // set the datasource and delegate for the inner collection
    guard let outerViewCell = cell as? OuterCollectionCell else { return }
    let dataProvider = InnerDatasourceDelegate()
    let delegate = InnerDatasourceDelegate()
    outerViewCell.initializeCollectionViewWithDataSource(dataProvider, delegate: delegate, forItem: indexPath.item)
    outerViewCell.innerCollectionView.reloadData()
    outerViewCell.innerCollectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
}

}
```

This InnerDataSourceDelegate class just has the same functions as above that are required to populate the cells.

And my custom cell class that has reference to the "inner" collectionView and contains the initializeCollectionViewWithDataSource function called above:

```
class OuterCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {

var collectionViewDataSource : UICollectionViewDataSource!
var collectionViewDelegate : UICollectionViewDelegate!


// define the smaller collection view that is in the cell
@IBOutlet var innerCollectionView: UICollectionView!

// set delegate and datasource for new collectionView
func initializeCollectionViewWithDataSource<D: UICollectionViewDataSource, E: UICollectionViewDelegate>(_ dataSource: D, delegate :E, forItem item: Int) {

    self.collectionViewDataSource = dataSource
    self.collectionViewDelegate = delegate

    innerCollectionView.delegate = self.collectionViewDelegate
    innerCollectionView.dataSource = self.collectionViewDataSource
    innerCollectionView.tag = item


    innerCollectionView.reloadData()
    innerCollectionView.layoutIfNeeded()

}
```

It displays fine when it is first loaded:

[image]

But when i select a cell it prints as i have asked:

```
cell no: 0 of collection view: 2
```

And then i get a fatal error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

In my ViewController class on this line:

```
outerCollectionView.dataSource = outerDataProvider
```

because outerCollectionView is nil.  But i can not figure out why it is nil.  Im not sure why its going through viewDidLoad again as this loaded when the ViewController now won't load again until i leave the VC and come back?

----- EDIT ------

Comment: Will you share demo ? If you dont mind, I will check and return back to you with solution

Comment: what is code on didSelect on collectionview's cell

Comment: Ill try add all the code from the classes